# разместить горизонтально блок за блоком

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой .css:

```
div.content{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 74%;
height: 600px;
display: inline-block;
}
div.leftBlock{
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
display: inline-block;
width: 25%;
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

И на выходе я имею, что блок `content` находится под `leftBlock`, теряется какая то часть разметки, но я не пойму почему. Но если ввести ширину `leftBlock` 24.50%, вместо 25% ,то всё работает, но это не дело. В чем причина подскажите плз.

Comment: используйте флекс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но если ввести ширину leftBlock 24.50%, вместо 25% ,то всё работает,
>   но это не дело. В чем причина подскажите плз.

Причина в `border`. У вас получается, что 25% + 1% + 74% = 100%, но у Вас есть ещё `border: 1px solid black;` слева и справа (и их 2: на **leftBlock** и на **content**) - а значит это уже 4px. Можете сделать так для блока **content**:

```
width: calc(74% - 4px);
```

Или использовать свойство `box-sizing: border-box;` на обоих блоках (тогда `calc` не нужен).

Но лучше используйте флексбокс:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 74%;
}

.leftBlock {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftBlock"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```